# Entity Framework Migration - The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a migration to add a DateTime field to an existing entity `User`:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("User", "UpdatedDate", c => c.DateTime(nullable: false, defaultValue: DateTime.Now));
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropColumn("User", "UpdatedDate");
    }
```

When running the `Update-Database` command to run the migration, the following error occurs:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

Interestingly, the migration runs fine, the column is inserted with the default value of the current datetime, but this exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN on datetime2:

> Defines a date that is combined with a time of day that is based on 24-hour clock. datetime2 can be considered as an extension of the existing datetime type that has a **larger date range, a larger default fractional precision**, and optional user-specified precision.

I'm guessing datetime2 is bigger than datetime because it's more precise, which is why you get an out-of-range exception.

Comment: Where do I go from here?

Comment: SqlDatetime minimum value is january 1 1753, for normal datetime it is 01 01 0001. I think you have to make sure your datetime is bigger than minimum sqldatetime

Comment: Well the column in the db is `datetime` and the default value I'm passing in is DateTime.Now, so in both cases it is above the default (I promise I'm not posting from the 18th century)

Comment: modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>() 
            .Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("datetime2")); This is all I could find

Answer (score 0):

In previous versions Entity used to complain with such error a lot, but the reason was not literally the conversion.

Often property was null on model, but database doesn't allow nulls.

Please verify that it is not the case for you. As you have some User with UpdatedDate = null somewhere.

Comment: There shouldn't be any with null as the default value is being inserted as soon as the column is created. Even if a default value isn't passed in, the database populates the field with a default value of something like 01 01 0001 etc

Comment: default value inserted in db not in context of an app, I would just decrease options by allowing nulls and then default value to see what exactly make it throw.